# "Call to a member function put() on null" in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Below I got my middleware that returns message to user

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
      $error = [
        'title' => 'Brak dostępu',
        'description' => '123'
      ];
      $request->session->put('error', $error);

return $next($request);
  }
```

Some notification is poping me up "Call to a member function put() on null" Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: This means that `$request->session` is `null`, so `->put()` is not available. Perhaps try with the helper `session()->put(...)` and see if that works?

Comment: try with facade Session::put('error', $error);

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is because it isn't the property `session`, its the method `session`:

```
$request->session()->.....
```

[Laravel 5.5 Docs - Session - Retrieving Data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#retrieving-data)